# new node buffers already have data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Is this a bug with node or expected behavior?  Reproducible in `0.12.7` and `io 3.1.0`:

```
> new Buffer(5)
<Buffer 00 00 02 00 00>
> new Buffer(5)
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00>
> new Buffer(5)
<Buffer 28 94 00 02 01>
> new Buffer(5)
<Buffer 00 00 00 02 00>
> new Buffer(5)
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00>
> new Buffer(5)
<Buffer 00 98 94 00 02>
```

Comment: I guess that we should not take anything from a buffer before we write something into it, so nodejs just not empty it for us(as it cost additional time to overwrite data in buffer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has pretty much always been the case. Zeroing memory adds overhead, so when you create a new Buffer, you see the contents of whatever that chunk of memory contained last.

If you need/want to zero out the Buffer, just do `buffer.fill(0);`

**UPDATE:**

With node v6.0.0 the [Buffer creation API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe) has changed. You can now directly allocate a zero-filled via `Buffer.alloc(size)` and get the old behavior via `Buffer.allocUnsafe(size)`. These new `Buffer` APIs have also been backported to v4.x in v4.5.0. The `new Buffer()`-style of Buffer creation is now considered deprecated <s>and will be removed in a future major version (probably v8.0.0 at the earliest if I had to guess, to allow for a hard deprecation cycle)</s>.

Additionally, since node v5.10.0 (and v4.5.0 for v4.x branch), you can pass the `--zero-fill-buffers` argument to the node binary which will silently and automatically zero-fill all Buffers upon creation.